# Can power mock allow the functionalities of mockito?

Tags: java-native-interface, mockito, powermock

I have existing code which uses mockito to mock the public interface in class.
I am adding some static methods in same class so planing to use powermock. 
Does powermock allow to keep the existing functionality of mockito ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  While SO is a great place to ask for help with programming problems, it is expected that the user provides examples of what they have tried so far.  This is intended as a resource for help when you are stuck, not as a tool to get others to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

From PowerMock's [Getting Started Page](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted):

> PowerMock consists of two extension API's. One for EasyMock and one for Mockito. To use PowerMock you need to depend on one of these API's as well as a test framework. Currently PowerMock supports JUnit and TestNG.

If you are using PowerMock and its Mockito extension API, you will also depend on Mockito—and these two tools interact just fine. Use pure Mockito wherever possible, and use PowerMock to handle legacy code cases and other places where you need to mock final classes, final/static methods, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, appreciate it .